# Import databases infos from mysql in database.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to get databases informations stored in my database and add it in the **database.php**.
I tried to get all infos in the database but I always have an error like this :

> [2019-04-18 20:22:20] laravel.ERROR: Call to a member function
>   connection() on null {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Call to a member function connection() on null at
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.net/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1249)

I added this on the top of **database.php** :

```
<?php

use App\Campaign;

$database_infos = Campaign::all();

$campains_db = array();

foreach ($database_infos as $info) {
    if (isset($info->db_name)) {
        $campains_db[$info->keyword] = array(
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => $info->db_host,
            'database' => $info->db_name,
            'username' => $info->db_user,
            'password' => decrypt($info->db_password),
            'prefix' => $info->db_prefix,
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        );
    }
}


return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [

        $campains_db,

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'wordpress' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',


    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Could you post your entire database.php?

Comment: I added all the file

Answer (score 0):

I found this on an other post :

> The simplest solution is to set your database config at runtime.
>   Laravel might expect these settings to be loaded from the
>   config/database.php file, but that doesn't mean you can't set or
>   change them later on.
>   The config loaded from config/database.php is stored as database in
>   Laravel config. Meaning, the connections array inside
>   config/database.php is stored at database.connections.

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
    "host" => "...",
    "database" => "...",
    "username" => "...",
    "password" => "..."
]);
```

Comment: Please do not post another answer as your own. Posts have an option to flag as duplicate, please use it.